# Peano axioms without identity and function symbols

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, relations, predicate-logic, peano-axioms

Can the [first-order Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) be reformulated without [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) and without [function symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Non-logical_symbols)? I tried doing this by characterizing one of the following relations axiomatically, but end up with unintended [models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_(logic)) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations) for the meaning of these terms):

**succeeds**

1. irreflexive
2. left-total
3. not right-total (zero)
4. discrete: $\forall x y (Rxy \to \neg \exists z (Rxz \land Rzy))$
5. ...

**less-than**

1. irreflexive
2. left-total
3. not right-total (zero)
4. transitive
5. ...

**less-than-or-equal-to**

1. reflexive
2. transitive
3. strongly connex
4. ...

Left- and right- uniqueness cannot be axiomatized as usual due to the lack of identity. (Left-totality + right-uniqueness + left-uniqueness + non-right-totality would suffice for the succeeds relation.)

Comment: It is unclear to me what kinds of models you intend to exclude. If you have no equality or function symbols in your language it will always be possible to construct a new model $M \amalg M$ from a model $M$ by taking as its relations those of $M$ except doubled (quadrupled, octupled, etc. as appropriate to its arity).

Comment: You can always get rid of function symbols and equality using relation symbols.

Comment: @ZhenLin And with no function symbols we can also "blow up" a single element: e.g. the natural numbers but with three copies of $2$, specifically.

Answer (score 1):

No. By the [upward Lowenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), there will always be models of higher cardinality once one can show the existence of an infinite model. So one can't zero in on the intended model $\mathbb{N}$ exactly with a first-order theory. Hence the necessity for a second-order axiom like the induction axiom.

Another problem is that without function symbols, the [Herbrand Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_universe) is finite. So there might be problems assuring that the models are all infinite.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph: I'm aware of the LS theorem. What I meant by unintended models is models that do *not* possess an initial segment isomorphic to the standard natural numbers (like every model of first-order PA does). I thought this would be implied by the fact that I'm trying to replicate what first-order PA does, but I should have been more clear about it in the question.